# jPlayer on loadcomplete event

Tags: jquery, html, events, audio, jplayer

I have custom preloader with css3 animation in my application, but when sound complete loading  preloader still moves. I searched in documentation on jplayer.org but it seems it was nothing like this, to hide this preloader when data was loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found answer for this question:

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").bind($.jPlayer.event.progress, function (event) {
   if (event.jPlayer.status.seekPercent === 100) {
     // loading complete
    } else {
     // Still loading
    }
});
```